# Shell Script to check content of PDF Files

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to check the content of PDF Files and output a specified string?

With this shell script i get all files in a loop

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER_NAME="pdffiles"

for fileName in "${FOLDER_NAME}"/*.pdf; do
        echo ${fileName}
        echo ""
done
```

Now i search a solution for check any content and get content with regex. I will try to write a samlpe

```
result=$(ls -l | pdfgrep -ei "hallo.*name" YourFile.pdf)
if [ ! -z "$result" ]
then
    # I don't know if the regex is correct
    specifiedNumber="/My specified String(\s+)(\d+)/" #Content is "My specified string   234524346"
    echo $specifiedNumber #Result 234524346
fi
```

At this moment I try pdfgrep, but I don't find a solution for my regex and the two if conditions

Thank for any help

EDIT: This is my new script

```
for fileName in "${FOLDER_NAME}"/*.pdf; do

        result=$(pdfgrep -i "company.*invoice" "$fileName")
        if [ ! -z "$result" ]
        then
                number=$(pdfgrep -Po '(?<=Invoicenumber)\s+\d+' "$fileName")
                echo "Company - $number"
        fi
done
```

Comment: `echo ${fileName}` is just as incorrect as `echo $fileName`. If you want to prevent undesired string-splitting and glob expansion, you need double quotes on the outside, as in `echo "$fileName"` or `echo "${fileName}"`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and/or run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Note that `\s` and `\d` are PCRE extensions. Standard regex syntax uses `[[:space:]]` and `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Comment: (Also, consider adding your own answer *as an answer* instead of editing it into the question; that way it can be commented on/upvoted/downvoted/etc independent of the question itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, I think you are looking for `"My specified string NNN"` in any PDF, so you need a Perl PCRE with `pdfgrep -Po` like this:

```
pdfgrep -Po '(?<=My specified string )\d+' *.pdf
```

**Original Answer**

I think you mean you want to search for **either** of two things in a PDF:

```
pdfgrep -e "hallo|name" YourFile.pdf
```

Or maybe you want to search for **both** of two things:

```
pdfgrep "hallo" YourFile.pdf && pdfgrep "name" YourFile.pdf && echo "Both present"
```

Or, you can get a list of all files that contain "string1" with:

```
pdfgrep -l "string1" *pdf
```

Or, get a list of files that contain "string1" and then look only in those files for "string2":

```
pdfgrep -lZ "string1" *pdf | xargs -0 pdfgrep -l "string2"
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have edit my first post and change my if conditions. This work well with your information. The last question is How I get only the Number of the sctring (the regex part in the if conditions. Have you any idea for this?

Comment: Mmmm... your edited post has several new problems. You want to look in all PDFs in the current directory and find the string `"My string is NNN"` and get `NNN`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. My goal is to check all files. In my for loop i will add different if conditions and rename my pdf with content informations from pdf. The different if conditions are for different file types..contracts, invoices and other

Comment: @Koda, ...note that generally speaking, if your first question has been answered, a follow-up question should be asked as a new/different question, not done as an edit that invalidates existing, previously-correct answers.